# How do I update the maven install plugin without a project POM?

Tags: java, maven

I am hoping to use `mvn install:install-file` to read the version and group from a JARs POM according to [these directions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

I can get this to work by explicitly declaring the install plugin version with: `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.1:install-file -Dfile=somejar.jar`

No project is defined. I am trying to load these JARs from a directory which is not part of a project. These JARs were compiled using maven and do have a POM in META-INF. How can I update the version of the install plugin system-wide?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Well, not unless you start fiddling with the Maven installation itself. This version is inside `lib/maven-core.jar!/META-INF/plexus/components.xml`...

Comment: Using a corporate pom file where you can define such things...Manually installing a plugin is not a good idea. Alway define the plugin version within your build (pom.xml) file...

Comment: what is the problem with using the plugin:version-number as you have mentioned above?

Comment: @Hishamkh defining the version number works but I'd prefer to just have the latest version installed so the shorter command can be used.

Comment: @Freiheit setting the plugin version is a good thing or you take the chance  to use an unstable version. When you don't, maven uses the one set in the maven settings. To know the default version you can use the following command : 
mvn help:effective-pom but you need a pom file to use it.

Comment: @XavierBouclet the essence of my question is how do I change the default version of a plugin? Is that built in to maven or configurable? In my case the built-in default was version 2.4 while version 2.5.1 was suitable for my needs

Comment: @Freiheit Sorry if misunderstood you. It's built in with your maven version. I haven't tried the latest version of maven to know if the install plugin version used is more recent than 2.4. To override it you have to use a pom or specify the version in your command line.  May be you could use a properties in your settings.xml or a variable to avoid the version in your command line or have you tried to define a profile in your settings.xml with a build part containing your install plugin informations?

Comment: I think that would be controlled by plugin-registry.xml, according to this reference plugin-registry.xml is dormant, https://maven.apache.org/settings.html . That suggests to me that what I am trying to do is not the best approach.